# Error when get value from string text?

Tags: php

I have a from text:

```
$text = 'abc def abc ghi abc jkl';
$search = 'abc';
$regex = '/'.trim($search).'/ism';
if(preg_match_all($regex, $text, $tmp)) {
   $array_key = $tmp[0];
   foreach($array_key as $ak) {
       echo $ak[1];
   }
}
```

When I echo $ak[1] is result is **b**, I want result is **abc**, how to fix it

abc def **abc** ghi abc jkl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(preg_match_all($regex, $text, $tmp)) {
   $array_key = $tmp[0];
   echo $array_key[1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about `echo $ak;` inside your loop?

`$ak[1]` is the second character in the matches, thus yielding `b`

Answer (score 1):

Well, `$tmp` will have an array of all the fields in your regex. Then those arrays will consist of all values for those fields.

What your code effectively does is `$ak = $tmp[0][$x] = "abc"` and when you take `$ak[1]` you go down one level further than the array actually has and get `"abc"[1] = "b"`.

I think you want to `echo $ak;` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
I am trying to discuss within your code. I hope its will help

<?php
$text = 'abc def abc ghi abc jkl';
$search = 'abc';
$regex = '/'.trim($search).'/ism';
if(preg_match_all($regex, $text, $tmp)) 
{
  $array_key = $tmp[0];

  /*Test using print_r($tmp); 
    then you will find result: Array( [0] => Array ( [0] => abc [1] => abc [2] =>      
     abc) ) 
   If you want to test/print first array value then echo $array_key[0]; result is: abc
   Similarly for $array_key[1] or $array_key[2] result is abc
   That means your array contains 3 same value
   */

   foreach($array_key as $ak) 
   {
    /*If you use echo $ak[1]; then it will print b because in foreach loop $ak value   
    is:  abc 
    You can't print only abc in foreach loop. To print abc you don't need to use   
    foreach loop. Just use echo $array_key[0]; 
   */ 
   }
  }
  ?>

  Maybe your expected code is:
  <?php
    $text = 'abc def abc ghi abc jkl';
    $search = 'abc';
    $regex = '/'.trim($search).'/ism';
    if(preg_match_all($regex, $text, $tmp)) 
    {
     $array_key = $tmp[0];
     echo $array_key[0];
    }
   ?>
  Output: abc
```